# Remove of markers in prunecluster

Tags: javascript, filter, leaflet

I load markers on the map. How to properly filter them? I tried to remove all markers via the RemoveMarkers () function, but they still just do not render. The idea is to remove all markers and request new markers to place them on the map. However, I can not remove the old markers. I tried to delete the entire .remove() layer, but this does not help

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you load some markers on map and you later want to clear them and add new markers. In order to clear them, you can add them to a layerGroup.

Check documentation:http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#layergroup. You can later call the

```
clearLayers()
```

method and add new markers on the layerGroup.